# What factors should I consider when choosing a high amperage power supply?

Tags: power-supply, power, switch-mode-power-supply, amperage

I've searched around, but I haven't found an answer to this particular question yet.

I'm building an elecromechanical project which requires somewhere around 60 Amps at 12 Volts. While this may not really be high amperage, it's more than the <10A supplies I've worked with before. I've been trying to understand how to pick the right power supply for my needs, but I'm not sure I understand everything that factors into the decision.

I'm fairly certain I want a regulated switching power supply, but I'm not really sure what differentiates the many available on the market.

For example,  I see this 750 watt power supply from 
jameco: https://www.jameco.com/z/SP-750-12-MEAN-WELL-AC-to-DC-Switching-Enclosed-Power-Supply-12-Volts-62-5-Amps-750-Watts_319944.html

What makes it so different (and more expensive) than this EVGA PC power supply: https://www.evga.com/products/product.aspx?pn=220-G2-0750-XR

They both give me 62 amps on the 12V rail, and in fact, the EVGA is more efficient. So what other discriminating factors should I be looking at?

Comment: Typically such a requirement is mistaken and you should use a higher voltage and lower current, but there may be exceptions.  What exactly are you doing?  Can your load dump energy back into the supply?

Comment: A PC power supply has the benefit of commodity pricing. It also has the benefit of a predictable load - a PC - which doesn't do a lot of the nasty things electromechanical systems do to power supplies, like stall currents, inductive spikes and regenerative braking.

Comment: A PC power supply might have the 12 V rail split among several independent rails of less power (one for the motherboard, one for the PCIe power connector, etcetera) instead of one big power supply. This might give problem with regulation at high load.

Comment: @ChrisStratton well, I have various electromechanical devices, motors, solenoids, etc. that are being driven off 12V, and I need around 50-60 amps to run them all. There are protections in place to prevent the loads from dumping current back into the power supply.

Comment: @BrianDrummond that's exactly the kind of thing I'm asking about, thanks. What specifications/power supply features should I be looking for, so that I know it can handle a messy load like electrochemical devices?

Comment: @JBeret It's actually a good question. +1. Hooking up large motors, big inductors, etc, depending on mechanical loading and other factors, can wreck havoc on some power supplies. A good, thoughtful answer will also be interesting.